# One way web service still returns a response

Tags: wcf, web-services

I aplogise if my terminology is inaccurate, still deep in learning.

I am creating a web service to act as an intermediary between Silverlight and XMPP. To start all of this I have created a web service call to enable me to ask the server to log on on my behalf and the idea is that the server will log on and then push back to my client once complete.

I have based the idea on the code form this site: http://weblogs.asp.net/dwahlin/archive/2011/02/06/syncing-data-with-a-server-using-silverlight-and-http-polling-duplex.aspx

Now the problem I have is that the Register call I have created will use an asynchronous call to log into XMPP. But the register call itself is also asychronous. So I don't know the best way for a web service call to wait for another service's async call

What I thought of doing was making the Register a one way call with the idea being that my server will log into XMPP then push the client once logged in (or fileld etc)

```
[OperationContract(IsOneWay = true)]
void Register(string name, string password, string nickname);
```

But when I imported the Service Reference the class generated appears to have a RegisterCompleted() call which debug shows is invoked. But I thought one-way meant no response is called so why is it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

One Way means No Response Data.  Internet protocols are a request-response model where there is an acknowledgement for the receipt of the request. Your Register service returns no data (void) so RegisterCompleted really did "completed accepting three string parameters and returned no data".

This is a good thing - now you know if you had a problem starting the registration or everything is good so business as usual until you hear back from the server.  You don't know yet if you're actually registered yet so that's why your client continues to Poll the server until the server responds - good or bad.

His [previous article](http://weblogs.asp.net/dwahlin/archive/2008/06/16/pushing-data-to-a-silverlight-client-with-wcf-duplex-service-part-i.aspx) references an good [MSDN example](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc645027%28VS.95%29.aspx) on using the PollingDuplexHttpBinding.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. It is very helpful to my understanding